# Remove all R Data objects from Global Environment

Tags: r, rstudio

I need a function to remove all objects on Data field of Global Environment (the one highlighted below).
I don't know specifically all classes of objects that appears there, however, I would like to remove everything, except for vectors, integers and functions.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data tab seems to hold anything with more than one dimension.

If you do `ls()`, you get character strings of the names of all the objects in the global environment. You can represent any of these objects by calling `get("object_name")`, so you can get the number of dimensions it has by calling `length(dim(get("object_name")))`. If this value is greater than 1, you know this is one of the objects you want to remove.

Therefore, all you need to do is apply `length(dim(get("object_name"))) > 1` to the names of the global objects, as obtained by `ls()`. You can do this with `sapply`:

```r
rm(list = ls()[sapply(ls(), function(x) length(dim(get(x))) > 1)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code: in place of those variables you want to keep place in quotes see below example.

```
rm(list=setdiff(ls(), "keep_variable"))
```

Another option is to change list to grid and click on the variables you don't want and press clean button. That will remove all unwanted variables.